# Gunicorn/Nginx/Flask not playing together well

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, puppet

I have been trying the last couple days to build a nginx/gunicorn/flask stack in Puppet to deploy repeatedly in our environment. Unfortunately, I am coming up short at the last moment and could really use some help. I have dumped anything I though relevant below, if anyone can lend a hand it would be very helpful!

gunicorn cli errors

```
(pyvenv) [root@guadalupe project1]# gunicorn wsgi:application
[2022-12-01 15:07:29 -0700] [13060] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-12-01 15:07:29 -0700] [13060] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (13060)
[2022-12-01 15:07:29 -0700] [13060] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-12-01 15:07:29 -0700] [13063] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13063
^C[2022-12-01 15:08:01 -0700] [13060] [INFO] Handling signal: int
[2022-12-01 15:08:01 -0700] [13063] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13063)
[2022-12-01 15:08:01 -0700] [13060] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
(pyvenv) [root@guadalupe project1]# gunicorn wsgi:application -b project1.sock
[2022-12-01 15:08:09 -0700] [13067] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-12-01 15:08:09 -0700] [13067] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2022-12-01 15:08:10 -0700] [13067] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2022-12-01 15:08:11 -0700] [13067] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2022-12-01 15:08:12 -0700] [13067] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2022-12-01 15:08:13 -0700] [13067] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2022-12-01 15:08:14 -0700] [13067] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('project1.sock', 8000)
```

gunicorn debug log from running

$ gunicorn wsgi:application -b project1.sock --error-logfile error.log --log-level 'debug'

```
    [2022-12-01 15:28:04 -0700] [16349] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
      config: ./gunicorn.conf.py
      wsgi_app: None
      bind: ['project1.sock']
      backlog: 2048
      workers: 1
      worker_class: sync
      threads: 1
      worker_connections: 1000
      max_requests: 0
      max_requests_jitter: 0
      timeout: 30
      graceful_timeout: 30
      keepalive: 2
      limit_request_line: 4094
      limit_request_fields: 100
      limit_request_field_size: 8190
      reload: False
      reload_engine: auto
      reload_extra_files: []
      spew: False
      check_config: False
      print_config: False
      preload_app: False
      sendfile: None
      reuse_port: False
      chdir: /home/bit-web/pyvenv/project1
      daemon: False
      raw_env: []
      pidfile: None
      worker_tmp_dir: None
      user: 0
      group: 0
      umask: 0
      initgroups: False
      tmp_upload_dir: None
      secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
      forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
      accesslog: None
      disable_redirect_access_to_syslog: False
      access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
      errorlog: error.log
      loglevel: debug
      capture_output: False
      logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
      logconfig: None
      logconfig_dict: {}
      syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
      syslog: False
      syslog_prefix: None
      syslog_facility: user
      enable_stdio_inheritance: False
      statsd_host: None
      dogstatsd_tags:
      statsd_prefix:
      proc_name: None
      default_proc_name: wsgi:application
      pythonpath: None
      paste: None
      on_starting: <function OnStarting.on_starting at 0x7f7b0fa6eae8>
      on_reload: <function OnReload.on_reload at 0x7f7b0fa6ebf8>
      when_ready: <function WhenReady.when_ready at 0x7f7b0fa6ed08>
      pre_fork: <function Prefork.pre_fork at 0x7f7b0fa6ee18>
      post_fork: <function Postfork.post_fork at 0x7f7b0fa6ef28>
      post_worker_init: <function PostWorkerInit.post_worker_init at 0x7f7b0fa860d0>
      worker_int: <function WorkerInt.worker_int at 0x7f7b0fa861e0>
      worker_abort: <function WorkerAbort.worker_abort at 0x7f7b0fa862f0>
      pre_exec: <function PreExec.pre_exec at 0x7f7b0fa86400>
      pre_request: <function PreRequest.pre_request at 0x7f7b0fa86510>
      post_request: <function PostRequest.post_request at 0x7f7b0fa86598>
      child_exit: <function ChildExit.child_exit at 0x7f7b0fa866a8>
      worker_exit: <function WorkerExit.worker_exit at 0x7f7b0fa867b8>
      nworkers_changed: <function NumWorkersChanged.nworkers_changed at 0x7f7b0fa868c8>
      on_exit: <function OnExit.on_exit at 0x7f7b0fa869d8>
      proxy_protocol: False
      proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
      keyfile: None
      certfile: None
      ssl_version: 2
      cert_reqs: 0
      ca_certs: None
      suppress_ragged_eofs: True
      do_handshake_on_connect: False
      ciphers: None
      raw_paste_global_conf: []
      strip_header_spaces: False
    [2022-12-01 15:28:04 -0700] [16349] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
    [2022-12-01 15:28:04 -0700] [16349] [DEBUG] connection to ('project1.sock', 8000) failed: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
    [2022-12-01 15:28:04 -0700] [16349] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
    [2022-12-01 15:28:05 -0700] [16349] [DEBUG] connection to ('project1.sock', 8000) failed: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
    [2022-12-01 15:28:05 -0700] [16349] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
    [2022-12-01 15:28:06 -0700] [16349] [DEBUG] connection to ('project1.sock', 8000) failed: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
    [2022-12-01 15:28:06 -0700] [16349] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
    [2022-12-01 15:28:07 -0700] [16349] [DEBUG] connection to ('project1.sock', 8000) failed: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
    [2022-12-01 15:28:07 -0700] [16349] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
    [2022-12-01 15:28:08 -0700] [16349] [DEBUG] connection to ('project1.sock', 8000) failed: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
    [2022-12-01 15:28:08 -0700] [16349] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
    [2022-12-01 15:28:09 -0700] [16349] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('project1.sock', 8000)
```

wsgi.py

```
    from flask import Flask
    application = Flask(__name__)
    @application.route("/")
    def hello():
        return "<h1 style='color:blue'>Hello There!</h1>"
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        application.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

the nginx.conf file that is being sourced from Puppet

```
    (pyvenv) [root@guadalupe project1]# cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/project1.conf
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    upstream app_a {
            server unix:///home/bit-web/pyvenv/project1/project1.sock;
    }
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name guadalupe.int.colorado.edu, 172.20.13.55;
    location / {
            proxy_read_timeout 300;
            proxy_connect_timeout 300;
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass app_a;
            }
    }
```

nginx error log

```
    2022/12/01 15:02:15 [error] 11743#11743: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 198.11.28.224, server: guadalupe.int.colorado.edu,, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///home/bit-web/pyvenv/project1/project1.sock:", host: "guadalupe.int.colorado.edu", referrer: "http://guadalupe.int.colorado.edu/"
```

socket information

```
    (pyvenv) [root@guadalupe project1]# ls
    project1.sock  __pycache__  wsgi.py
    (pyvenv) [root@guadalupe project1]# pwd
    /home/bit-web/pyvenv/project1
```

gunicorn service

```
    (pyvenv) [root@guadalupe project1]# cat /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service
    [Unit]
    Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
    After=network.target
    [Service]
    User=bit-web
    Group=nginx
    WorkingDirectory=/home/bit-web/pyvenv/project1
    Environment="PATH=/home/bit-web/pyvenv/bin"
    ExecStart=/home/bit-web/pyvenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:project1.sock -m 007 wsgi:application
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: [This may help.](https://github.com/voxpupuli/puppet-keepalived/issues/143)

Answer (score 0):

in your gunicorn service file, Instead of

```
ExecStart=/home/bit-web/pyvenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:project1.sock -m 007 wsgi:application
```

try this (means add .sock file path)

```
ExecStart=/home/bit-web/pyvenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/bit-web/pyvenv/project1/project1.sock -m 007 wsgi:application
```

Comment: Tried this just now, it did not work unfortunately. Same error.

Comment: See if it can help you....https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-22-04